# Related to testing framework- Mocha

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, blockchain, ethereum

I am developing simple DApps using Ethereum platform. And in this, I have used Mocha test framework but coming with this error. Please help...

E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo>npm run test

> demo@1.0.0 test E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo
> mocha

```
TypeError: Suite argument "title" must be a string. Received type "function"
    at createInvalidArgumentTypeError (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\errors.js:158:13)
    at new Suite (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\suite.js:45:15)
    at Function.Suite.create (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\suite.js:26:17)
    at Object.create (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\interfaces\common.js:128:27)
    at context.describe.context.context (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\interfaces\bdd.js:42:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\test\inbox_test.js:13:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.exports.requireOrImport (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:20:12)
    at Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\esm-utils.js:33:34)
    at Mocha.loadFilesAsync (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\mocha.js:421:19)
    at singleRun (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:156:15)
    at exports.runMocha (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run-helpers.js:225:10)
    at Object.exports.handler (E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\lib\cli\run.js:366:11)
    at E:\Tutorials\Blockchain\Practicle\Demo\node_modules\mocha\node_modules\yargs\lib\command.js:241:49
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! demo@1.0.0 test: `mocha`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the demo@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Prabhakar's\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-21T05_32_41_476Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score -1):

I got my answer. And I m posting it so that it can be helpful others...

Earlier I have defined my describe method as:

```
describe(() => {
it("can pass the test", () => {
    console.log(accounts);
});
```

});
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru0sV.png)

and here direct function I have passed instead of going for tittle first that's why mocha wasn't able to make it and return with error :

> Suite argument "title" must be a string. Received type "function"

But after giving my contract method it accepts it as a tittle

```
describe( 'inbox', () => {
it("can pass the test", () => {
    console.log(accounts);
});
```

});
[Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrGM.png)